# How can i "intercept" request in jest using enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, sinon, enzyme, jsdom

I have an action that is using RSAA from `redux-api-middleware` called createUser:

```
export const createUser = values => {
  const email = values.get("user_attributes[email]");
  const password = values.get("user_attributes[password]");
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: `${globalVar.API_URL}/users/`,
        method: "POST",
        body: values,
        types: [
          CREATE_USER,
          {
            type: CREATE_USER_SUCCESS,
            payload: (action, state, response) => {
              return response.json().then(json => {
                dispatch(login(email, password));
                dispatch(sendFlashMessage("success", json.message));
                return json;
              });
            }
          },
          CREATE_USER_FAILURE
        ]
      }
    });
  };
};
```

...And I have a component with `redux-form` that use this action:

```
class UserNew extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    values = { user_attributes: values };
    const data = objectToFormData(values);
    this.props.actions.createUser(data);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, errors } = this.props;
    return (
      <UserForm
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        errors={errors}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In my `jest` with `enzyme` test file:

```
it("create new user", done => {
  wrapper
    .find("#sign-up")
    .hostNodes()
    .simulate("click");

  wrapper
    .find('[name="first_name"]')
    .hostNodes()
    .simulate("change", { target: { value: "User" } });

 ...
```

...and after completing the form:

```
wrapper
  .find("form")
  .hostNodes()
  .simulate("submit");
done();
```

but it crash:
[image]

So, I want to intercept API call and let it finish executing the action as such (dispatching login and sendFlashMessage).

I tried `moxios` but it didn't work:

```
moxios.install();
moxios.stubRequest(`${globalVar.API_URL}/users/`, {
  status: 200,
  response: [{user: {...}, message: "OK"}]
});
```

I'm trying use `sinon` to resolve this

Comment: post your sinon code

Comment: what is RSAA? google tells me nothing

Comment: I think RSAA is the same as CALL_API:

`import { CALL_API, RSAA } from 'redux-api-middleware';`

Comment: Hey, was your question answered or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/) with [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react) and [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/).

example code:

```
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import sinon from "sinon";

beforeAll(() => {
 server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
 const initialState = {
  example: ExampleData,
  auth: AuthData
 };
 wrapper = mount(
  <Root initialState={initialState}>
    <ExampleContainer />
  </Root>
 );
});

it("example description", () => {
  server.respondWith("POST", "/api/v1/example", [
    200,
      { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      'message: "Example message OK"'
    ]);
  server.respond();
  expect(wrapper.find(".response").text().to.equal('Example message OK');
})
```

In the code above we can see how to intercept API calls using the test DOM created by the enzyme and then mock API responses using sinon.

Answer (score 0):

Sinon doesn't have any immediate way of resolving this for you using its fake XHR machinery. The reason is clear from the [middleware documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware) you are using:

> Note: redux-api-middleware depends on a global Fetch being available, and may require a polyfill for your runtime environment(s).

Sinon (or really its dependant [`nise` library](https://github.com/sinonjs/nise)) doesn't deal with Fetch, only XHR.

You could either employ a library like [fake-fetch](https://github.com/msn0/fake-fetch) or simply stub `fetch` yourself. That would involve quite an elaborate stub, though, including stubbing complicated responses, so I'd rather just do:

```
var fakeFetch = require('fake-fetch');

beforeEach(fakeFetch.install);
afterEach(fakeFetch.restore);

it("should fetch what you need", done => {
  fakeFetch.respondWith({"foo": "bar"});

  fetch('/my-service', {headers: new Headers({accept: 'application/json'})}).then(data => {
    expect(fakeFetch.getUrl()).toEqual('/my-service');
    expect(fakeFetch.getMethod()).toEqual('get');
    expect(data._bodyText).toEqual('{"foo":"bar"}');
    expect(fakeFetch.getRequestHeaders()).toEqual(new Headers({accept: 'application/json'}));
    done();
  });
});
```